# Change json.net configuration in NancyModule with negotiation

Tags: json.net, nancy

I have a case where I have two routes that will return different formatted json for the same model.  In one case I want to include the null values, in the other case I do not.

My solution for this was to create a second JsonSerializer and call it directly in the NancyModule, but I lose the flexibility of negotiation.  What I would like to do though is hook this into the Negotiation for something like this:

```
return Negotiate 
.WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK)
.WithModel( MyModel)
**.WithSerializer( MyCustomerJsonSerializer)**
.WithView("MyView");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to create your own IResponseProcessor, [like the existing Json one](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Responses/Negotiation/JsonProcessor.cs), and register it instead of the default one. In the processor, make sure you use different serializers based on the route (the current context is passed in the processor). Or you can make it to decide which serializer to use based on someting in the context's Item collection.

That way, one of the routes can set something on the context, and this will drive the processor to choose one or the other serializer.